# never fight vs never to fight

Tags: phrase-usage

I wonder if you could explain me why in the second sentence we need to use "to fight", needn't we? The first sentence is like a command and there is no need to use "to fight", but what about the second sentence?

> **Never fight** with him!
>
> Let's make a deal **never to fight** with him.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first is an *imperative*, or 'command'; the second uses an infinitive verb and so requires you to include 'to'.

You usually have a choice of where to place the negation with an infinitive, so you could say either:

- Let's make a deal **never to** fight with him.
- Let's make a deal **to never** fight with him.

Comment: Does it mean that "to" is also necessary in this context: "Let's make a deal **not to fight** with him." But "Let's make a deal **you fight** with him." - "to" isn't used because there is subject in the sentence. Am I right?